# Errors in evalauting an expression

Tags: equation-solving, functions

I have the following:

**Constants:**

```
b3b = 2;
G = (1/eps^2);
a1 = 3;
a3 = 4;
xc = 0.3;
```

**Functions:**

```
y[x_] := (x*a1 - x^3*a3)/G
n[x_] := (y[x]^2)
```

**I want `g[x], gp[x], gpp[x]` as functions of `eps` only and all of these three functions should be evaluated at `x=xc` :**

```
g[x_] := (G*(-y[x]/eps)*Exp[-n[x]] - (b3b/eps)*
     NIntegrate[(y[s])^4*Exp[-n[s]], {s, 0, xc}])
```

Please note that in the **integrand** above --> both `n[x]` and `y[x]` are functions of `eps` and so I can use `NIntegrate` since I am using `:=` for `g[x]` even though `eps` is not given a numerical value as yet. Everything is perfect till this point as I am able to get a numerical value for `g[xc]` for a `eps` value. The problem happens when I take the following derivatives:

```
 gp[x_] := D[g[x], x]
 gpp[x_] := D[gp[x], x]
```

since when I evaluate `gp[xc]` and `gpp[xc]` for a particular `eps` value, I get errors: `NIntegrate::inumr` and `General::ivar`.

Therefore, I need a way to get around this. I must be doing something wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @Nasser If I use the := for g[x] then isn't it fine to use NIntegrate? because at the end I have to plot a huge function that requires g[xc], gp[xc], gpp[xc] to be changing with eps..i tried the one you had up and got General::ivar can you please tell me what I can do?

Comment: @Nasser thanks for the help...apologies regarding that...can you please tell me what else I can do for my situation...can i use Integrate for g[x] instead and then take the derivatives? however, i still get an error when I evaluate the functions at x=xc for a particular eps...please help me as to what I can do

Comment: @Nasser i guess they didn't read your post...please help me

Comment: @Artes I reformulated the question as you suggested...can you please take a look now...i hope it makes more sense as to what I want to do now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is the way you defined the derivatives. Mma will evaluate e.g. in this order: gp[xc] -> D[g[xc], xc] and obviously you'll get an error there. You may define the derivatives like this:

```
gp[x_] := D[g[t], t] /. t -> x
gpp[x_] := D[g[t], {t, 2}] /. t -> x
```

And you'll get it working:

```
Block[{eps = 0.1}, {gp[xc], gpp[xc]}]

{-19.1964, 72.004}
```

Comment: you are amazing...thanks so much for this..been dying for this!